# using <script> in html page using sightly

Tags: javascript, google-maps, aem, sightly

I am trying to add google maps to a component that is using sightly. The component will let users select an asset and then grab the lat/long from the assets properties and then show the location with a marker in google map.

my `googlemap.html` page contains the following at the moment.

```
<div  data-sly-use.ev="Google"
        class="${ev.cssClass || ''}"
        title="${ev.title || ''}"
        data-emptytext="Evernote Asset"
        id="${ev.googleClass || ''}"
        >       

</div>

    <style>
             #map-canvas {
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
             }
    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

My Google.java is like this

```
public class Google extends WCMUse {
  public void activate () {
    //grab the lat/long properties for the asset
  }

  public String googleClass() {
    if (lat != null && long != null) 
      return "map-canvas";
    else 
      return "";
  }
  public String getLat() {return lat;}
  public String getLng() {return lng:]
}
```

**Question**
As you can see I have hardcoded the lat/long. How can I get the lat/long from my java class using the getters instead of hardcoding?

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
<div  data-sly-use.ev="GoogleMap"
        class="${ev.cssClass || ''}"
        title="${ev.title || ''}"
        data-emptytext="Evernote Asset"
        id="${ev.googleClass || ''}"
        >       



    <style>
             #map-canvas {
            width: 500px;
            height: 400px;
             }
    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng("${ev.lat || ''}","${ev.lng || ''}");
        var mapOptions = {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Sightly has XSS protection out the box. So in order to evaluate the expressions, the context should be used.

`${ev.lat @ context="scriptString"}`

Comment: For clarity - in HTML contexts, Sightly is usually able to determine the right XSS protection context to apply. Inside script or style tags, however, the parser can't figure out the right protection context, so it requires one to be manually specified (as in Anthony's example). A message along these lines also appears in the logs.

Answer (score -1):

Your Javascript runs client side in the browser so will not normally interact with your Java code running server side. You might want to expose your Java method as a RESTful API endpoint and perform an AJAX call in the Javascript code.

SEE: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials (ajax tutorial)

Other ways are creating object on server side and expose that object from session or from some static functions and then you can use JSP servlet syntax to access that object.

```
<LI>Curent time: <%= new java.util.Date() %> 
<LI>Host name: <%= request.getRemoteHost() %> 
<LI>ID sesion: <%= session.getId() %> 
</UL> 
<% deleteconfig deletecfg = new deleteconfig(); %>
<%= delectecfg.initiate(); =%>
</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

JSP scripting elements are:

Expressions: `<% = expression%>` The expression is evaluated and printed out the document.

Scriptlet `<% code%>` The code is inserted into the servlet service method.

Statements: `<%! code%>` The code is inserted into the servlet class, outside of any method.

For JSP scripting elements is possible and another syntactic form, based on XML markup:

```
<jsp:expression> Java expression </ jsp: expression>
<jsp:scriptlet> Java code </ jsp: scriptlet>
<jsp:declaration> Statement Java </ jsp: declaration>
```

I would prefer the first approach using restFul API. That will be more cleaner approach